# CSS "table-layout: fixed" and cell with auto-width by inner content

Tags: css, tablelayout

I have a problem with `table-layout:fixed` and width of inner columns if their content wider than column.

Look at my sample here:
http://jsfiddle.net/H5FLm/

Main idea  of this markup that I need centered column with auto-width by inner content and liquid columns on sides.

I'm opened for any suggestions to fix it or use different markup.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer using word-wrap instead of overflow. Check my version [here](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/H5FLm/5/)

Added `word-wrap: break-word;` to content class.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this layout, sounds like it's what you're looking for:

- http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-3-column.htm

The only reason your current layout doesn't work is because of your choice to use the string `looooooooooooooong` as your sample text. HTML does not wrap letters. Technically you can do `overflow: hidden;` and BOOM... problem fixed.

Had you used [`loo oooooo oooooo ong`](http://jsfiddle.net/H5FLm/4/), no problem.